# splicing between sequence of two defined boundaries

Tags: python, string, loops

I have created a function that takes in four strings. The first two strings will be long strings that can be anything. The last two strings will be referred to as boundaries. I want to take everything in string1 between the defined boundaries and replace everything in string2 between the defined boundaries. The part of the string taken away from string 1 will be removed and the part replaced in string 2 will be removed. An example of this function is below:

```
def bound('DOGYOMAMA','ROOGMEMAD', 'OG' 'MA') --> RETURNS('DMA','ROOGYOMAD', 
'OG', 'MA')
```

This is the function I have created to do what I wrote above

```
def bound(st,sz,a,b):
    s1=''.join(st)
    s2=''.join(sz)
    if a in s1 and b in s1 and a in s2 and b in s2:
        f1=s1.find(a)
        l1=s1.find(b)
        f2=s2.find(a)
        l2=s2.find(b)

        blen1 = len(b)
        blen2 = len(b)

        s1_n = s1[:f1] +s1[l1+blen1:]
        s2_n = s2[:f2] + s1[f1:l1 + blen1] +s2[l2+blen2]
        return s1_n, s2_n, a, b

print(bound('DOGYOMAMA','ROOGMEMAD', 'OG','MA'))
```

My problem is that I also need to make it so this will work in reverse so if I have `('DOGYOMAMA','ROOGMEMAD', 'OG' 'MA')` it should also look for `('AMAMOYGOD','DAMEMGOOR', 'GO' 'AM')`. Another thing would be if the string can be spliced both ways it will take only the sequence that is spliced at the lowest index.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! if you got the solution to your problem, you can let the User know by accepting his/her answer. If you didn't find solution comment on the issue of his/her solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

and if you have to return many items then don't return the output instead of store the output in a list and return that list at last , that i did there :

```
def bound(st,sz,a,b):
    result=[]
    string_s = [''.join(st), ''.join(sz), ''.join(st)[::-1], ''.join(sz)[::-1]]
    boundaries = [a, b, a[::-1], b[::-1]]
    for chunk in range(0, len(string_s), 2):
        word = string_s[chunk:chunk + 2]
        bound = boundaries[chunk:chunk + 2]
        if bound[0] in word[0] and bound[1] in word[0] and bound[0] in word[1] and bound[1] in word[1]:
            f1 = word[0].find(bound[0])
            l1 = word[0].find(bound[1])
            f2 = word[1].find(bound[0])
            l2 = word[1].find(bound[1])

            blen1 = len(bound[1])
            blen2 = len(bound[1])

            s1_n = word[0][:f1] + word[0][l1 + blen1:]


            s2_n = word[1][:f2] + word[0][f1:l1 + blen1] + word[1][l2 + blen2]
            result.append([s1_n, s2_n, bound[0], bound[1]])

    return result


print(bound('DOGYOMAMA','ROOGMEMAD', 'OG','MA'))
```

output:

```
[['DMA', 'ROOGYOMAD', 'OG', 'MA'], ['AMAMOYAMOYGOD', 'DAMEME', 'GO', 'AM']]
```